# How to execute custom installation commands during conda environment build?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I usually create my *conda* environments with `conda env create --file environment.yml`. However, inside the YAML file I can only specify *conda* packages, *PyPI* packages or GitHub repos. Is there a way to hook up any bash script with a custom piece of code (eg. installing an obscure library from a the depths of the internet) that will be automatically executed **after** the packages are installed? Similarly to [post-link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/link-scripts.html) scripts here, but for environment creation, not package build.

If not, do you know of any reasonable workaround?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no built-in solution in conda. But according to your requirement, why not just create some shell script:

```
conda env create -f environment.yaml
<command for installing an obscure library from the depths of the internet>
```

And just execute that script when you create the environment.